# SSIS Flat File [DT_DBTIMESTAMP] cant convert to SQL datetime2

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, bids

I created a running SSIS and I tried inserting data without error to SQL Server
but suddenly this error message pops up

> Error: 0xC02020A1 at Data Flow Task, Flat File Source [59]: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "SCB_ActualDTime" returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".

It says that the error occurred in row 8 containing these data from the

```
SCB_ActualDTime
2017-04-16 15:28:07
```

It is really weird because I tried inserting the same data via SQL script and there is no error message.

Comment: Try removing that row from your incoming data and see if you still get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Flat File` is not a data source that force a specific data types for each column. so it may contains unicode characters or white spaces that prevent reading column as Datetime.

After working with many cases i decided to work with flat file in this way.

- In the `Flat File Connection Manager` i will read all column as `DT_STR` column without specifying other data types
- Inside The `DataFlow  Task` i will add a script component to check if columns value can be converted to the estimated data type and then converted it

Assuming that the date column name is `inColumn`

In the DataflowTask, Add a script component , Mark `inColumn` as input column, add a new Output column `outColumn` with dataType DT_DBTIMESTAMP

*Change script language to vb.net*

[image]

*Mark your date column as Input*

[image]

*Create an Output column for each date column*

[image]

Inside the script, in `Input0_ProcessInputRow` sub use [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) Function as follow:

*In this example the date column is `MailReceivingDate`*

```
    Public Class ScriptMain
        Inherits UserComponent


        Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)

            If Not Row.MailReceivingDate_IsNull AndAlso
                  Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Row.MailReceivingDate.Trim) Then

                Dim dtDate as Date

               If DateTime.TryParseExact(Row.MailReceivingDate.Trim, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"),System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,dtDate) Then

                    Row.OutColumn = dtDate

               Else

                    'If column cannot be parsed

                    Row.outColumn_IsNull = True

               End If

            Else

                    Row.outColumn_IsNull = True

            End If

        End Sub

    End Class
```

Comment: I encountered an error in code line `DateTime.TryParseExact(Row.SCBActualDTime.Trim, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"), dtDate)`
The error message says `Overload resulotion failed because no accessible 'TryParseExact' accepts this number of arguments`. BTW I am using Microsoft VB 2012 if that matter.

Comment: sorry i missed on argument `DateTimeStyles` use the following code `DateTime.TryParseExact(Row.SCBActualDTime.Trim, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"),System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,dtDate)`

Comment: @VianOjedaGarcia i edited my answer. you can read more about this method in this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: One last thing before I accept your answer. What If I have another column to process. Will it create another sub for my column2?

Comment: @VianOjedaGarcia not `Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow` is for row processing , just repeat the code inside this Sub

Comment: @VianOjedaGarcia but you have to mark the other column as input and create a new output column for it

Comment: @VianOjedaGarcia also take care this code will set to Null every columns that cannot be parsed to date. Good Luck i will be offline for some time

Comment: Yeah I noticed it in the code. The problem is I still needed that date. I can't have a null date in my database.

Comment: You have to add your own code here. You have to decide if you will add a constant value or do some logic

Comment: If all dates are wel formatted it will note convert to null

Comment: Thank you very much. Very much appreciated

Comment: im trying to make a way to reuse the code. Because it kinda bug me to repeat the same code